# is there a react timetable component or package

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a school management system using react I want to have a timetable for both students and teachers is there a suitable react timetable package or component

**I want my timetable to be like this:-**
[image: my target timetable]

Comment: It's depend your back-end. For common usage you can use packages like [dx-react-scheduler][1].

In similar project I received months and events from back-end and mapped to custom UI.


  [1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler

Comment: thanks bro will definately check it out tomorrow , i will let you the outcome cheers mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [dx-react-scheduler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler) wasn't suite, I Suggest [@fullcalendar/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fullcalendar/react). you can check demoes [here](https://fullcalendar.io/demos).

Comment: thanks dx-react-scheduler works fine , will test full calender also